# I can't move my box I made

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, framed

Here is the problem, I made a box using

```
\begin{tabular}[b]{|l|}
\hline
example \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

I have the `[b]` meaning bottom, but the position never changes ... In general how do I manipulate the box to where I want it to be?

Please no fancy packages to install, I am new to this stuff

**EDIT**: Does anyone know how to add the boxes within `\begin{align*} ... \end{align*}`?

Comment: Do you want it to float with the document, or remain fixed somewhere? If so, be specific about the location.

Comment: The `[b]` argument will align the `tabular` to its bottom baseline. You only have one line, so this doesn't change anything. Note that you can draw a *frame* around some text using `\fbox`, no need to misuse `tabular` for this. Please update your question and state what you are trying to achieve. At the moment it's very vague and confusing, especially your `align*` edit.

Comment: What do you mean with *Please no fancy packages to install, I am new to this stuff* If you have installed TeX Live or MikTeX, nearly every package will be available by `\usepackage`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tabular` is non - *floating* body. Hence you need not use `[b]` for it. Remove the option and put the code where you want the box to appear. It does the job.

The following example shows various possibilities of placing the box (Still I am afraid that it is not clear to me where to place the box according to the question)

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{lipsum}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\lipsum[1]
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
    \hline
     example \\
     \hline
     \end{tabular}

\begin{parbox}[t]{0.818\textwidth}%
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
    \hline
     example \\
     \hline
     \end{tabular}
\end{parbox}
%
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
    \hline
     example \\
     \hline
     \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
    \hline
     example \\
     \hline
     \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[l]{\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
    \hline
     example \\
     \hline
     \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Still doesn't work. For instance, I am trying to make it appear in the middle of the page, but to the right. trying to make a point distribution thing for an exam.

Comment: you want it to be flushed to the right?

Comment: Yeah, somewhere in the middle to the right

Comment: @jak: See the edit and let me know..

Comment: Yes, the first three "examples" are what I need.

Comment: I@jak Is that helpful and enough?

Comment: Could you explain why you had |l| instead of |r| for all of them?

Comment: @jak: For all of them? You mean `minipage`? It is ok to put `l` or `r` or `c` as long as the `minipage` spans `\textwidth`. You are at freedom. For one `minipage` I used `c` with `\hfill` to illustrate this.

Comment: @jak: To put a box inside `align` use `\boxed` or `\Aboxed`